# Does any technical definition of embedding accept a "non-injective" function as opposed to only "injective"?

Tags: calculus, general-topology, algebraic-topology, machine-learning, low-dimensional-topology

[Embedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding) is defined to be a one-to-one structure preserving mapping.
My question is if the one-to-one condition is really critical.

Like if linear mappings from high-dimensional space to low-dimensional space  such as principal component analysis (PCA), could be technically considered as an embedding. 
Or perhaps another technical term should be used for them.
The reason I ask is that in other disciplines, say in machine learning, the term embedding is used a lot for dimensionality reduction methods, that are not one to one. 
(See the abstract of [this paper](https://www.cs.nyu.edu/~roweis/lle/papers/lleintro.pdf) for example.)

Comment: What do you mean by PCA?

Comment: Sorry. Principle Component Analysis.

Comment: How is that a map?  What are its domain and range?

Comment: In PCA, a vector $\in \mathbb{R}^n$ is projected  into a set of basis defined by a subset of  its principal components. Each principal components gets a a scalar coefficient. If we pick $k$ principal components, the range would be $\mathbb{R}^k$. Typically $k<n$ is picked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an embedding is by definition injective. If you change the definition, then it's not what anyone calls an embedding anymore.

It's like asking if the condition "every element has an inverse" is "really critical" in the definition of a group... Sure, you can consider "groups" where not all elements have inverses. Well, except nobody calls that a "group", but a monoid.

If your "embedding" is not injective, then it's not an "embedding" at all. You (and people from other fields of math or science) are free to call something else "embedding", but at least in the areas of math I know, an embedding is injective.

Comment: I see. As for "monoid" in your group and monoid example, do you have suggestions for a more appropriate mathematical term that can be used for a non-injective  structure preserving map?

Comment: @user25004 How about "a structure-preserving map", or "homomorphism", or even simply "morphism"?